# how can I config proxy with axios

Tags: proxy, axios, nuxt.js

I'm working with nuxt.

as the following you see I set config for axios and proxy in the nuxt.config.js but it dose not work and return http://localhost:3000/laravel/register 404 (Not Found)
but I need http://localhost:8000/register.

what is the problem?

#### nuxt.config.js

```
modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy',
],
 
  axios: {
    proxy:true,
    // baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
  },

  proxy: {
    '/laravel': {
      target: 'http://localhost:8000',
      pathRewrite: { '^/laravel': '/' }
    }
  },
```

### example use  axios

```
   Register() {
      try {
        const response = this.$axios.$post('/laravel/register', {
          data: this.form,
        })
        console.log(response)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    },
```

Comment: Hi, did you searched for similar questions on stackoverflow? There are quite some of them.

Comment: yes I found some similar questions but not worked for me

Comment: What did not worked? Can you give some details?

Comment: I try to give you some details on description